# How to efficiently initialize an array.array of a particular length in Python

Tags: python, arrays, memory-efficient

Looking at the available ways to initialize an `array.array` in Python, it appears that each of them either relies on creating a separate list of objects first or supplying an iterable that presumably may require heap reallocation and copying, possibly multiple times while appending values.

Is there any way to allocate storage once for a new `array.array` instance of a specific length without first allocating some other collection of that same length?

Answer (score 2):

Although the documentation for `array.array` does not currently mention addition or multiplication operators, it turns out that `array.array` does support those, so…

The most straightforward (and presumably efficient) means of initializing a large instance with the same value in every element is apparently to create an instance with length of 1 and multiply that times the desired number of elements.

```py
a = array('h', [0]) * 50000
print(len(a))
```

Output:

```
50000
```